# How to give a unique name to each USB interface?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver, usb-descriptor

I'm writing a device driver for a device that can have 2 speakers connected to it at the same time.

The 2 interfaces show up on the host (I'm using a Windows host) with the same name. How can I give each interface a unique name - like speaker 1 and speaker 2?

Comment: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#InterfaceDescriptors, `bInterfaceNumber` should be uniq.

Comment: I already have unique bInterfaceNumber values for each interface. That doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: i mean it just displays the `iInterface` value which i assume are the same here. `iInterface` + `bInterfaceNumber` should be uniq.

Comment: I have unique iInterface and bInterfaceNumber values for each interface. But Windows will simply not install the UAC driver.